# Objects creation using interface for JSON types in typescript

Tags: javascript, json, typescript

I am having a hard time understanding how the object types are formed given a JSON.  For example I have this JSON object which I need to form a type for.

```
// "Spokane, WA": {
  //   "My M": "M-Spokane-WA.json",
  //   "MY D": "D-Spokane-WA.json"
  // },
  // "Pondera, MT": {
  //   "My M": "M-Pondera-MT.json",
  //   "MY D": "D-Pondera-MT.json"
  // },
```

The rule I am following is copy the JSON while creating the object and then give the names to the variables. In the end I have something like this.

```
export interface IStateType {
cityState: string {   // "Spokane, WA" is in quotes so seems like is coming in string.
My M :string  // "My M" is string .. How to show the  "M-Spokane-WA.json" part???
MY D: string  
}
}
```

turned out this is the correct way to put it

```
export interface IStateType  {
     [cityState: string]: {
        ["My M"]: string;
        ["MY D"]: string;
      };
}
```

Can someone please explain why are we using [] for cityState  and why are there quotes around My M and My D but not around cityState?

--------------- Udpate 2
From the link on index signature

```
interface StringArray {
  [index: number]: string;  // It says string is a return type..
}

let myArray: StringArray;
myArray = ["Bob", "Fred"];  // Is this the return mentioned above :string?

let myStr: string = myArray[0];  // Is myArray[0] this the [index:number] part of interfaces StringArray?
```

Comment: This is not JavaScript. Please tag correctly.

Comment: @amadan, isnt it vanilla JS? What do you want me to tag it as?

Comment: Things that JavaScript doesn't have: interfaces, type declarations, a type called `string` (lowercase). I'd guess it's TypeScript (or possibly some related derivative)... but you should know better than me what language you're using.

Comment: Changed to typescript, thanks..

Comment: Because that's how TypeScript works, e.g., https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#indexable-types. `My M` on its own isn't a valid JavaScript identifier, so it has to be in quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us disassemble the interface definition.

```
export interface IStateType  {
    [cityState: string]: <some value type definition>,
}
```

We have a [index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#indexable-types) defined here. An index signature makes the interface able to have infinite number of properties matching the exact type. The key has to be of `string` type, and the value has to be of `<some value type definition>`

Then instead of `<some value type definition>`, it is actually:

```
{
    ["My M"]: string;
    ["MY D"]: string;
};
```

This is the same as

```
{
    "My M": string;
    "MY D": string;
};
```

You have to use quotation marks around `My M` and `My D` because there are white spaces in the string. If there are no spaces, you could have used `MyM` and `MyD` directly, without quotation marks.

---

You cannot use `["cityState"]` instead of `[cityState: string]`, because this is how you define an index signature.

The reason why you have to use `[cityState: string]` instead of `cityState: string` is because this lets you pass a JSON object of an arbitrary number of city states and just works. Your original interface definition accepts only one city state.

---

#### EDIT 1: Examples

I see some obvious mistakes in your code, so here is the corrected version.

```
interface StringArray {
  [index: number]: string;
}

let myArray: StringArray;
myArray = {0: "Fred"};

let myStr: string = myArray[0]; // "Fred"
```

Each property in `myArray` needs to have a `number` as `key`, and `string` as `value`. This is defined in the code `[index: number]: string`. The rest is self-explanatory imo.

---

Here is another example:

```
let myArray2: StringArray;
myArray2 = {
  4: "hello",
  7: "world",
  3643728: "enjoy",
  1: "good",
  5.2: "luck",  // 5.2 is a number
};

console.log(myArray2[5.2]); // Logs "luck"
```

Comment: This is the best explanation I have gotten. Thank you soo much! I do have a few more questions on this if thats ok. The link for index signature you sent.. I am updating my post.

Comment: Please refrain from the update question/update answer cycle @Sarah and Timmy. It's not fair to other people who may come along with other answers for the original question and Stack Overflow is meant for one question => one-to-many answers.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Actually I have thought about it, but instead of making Sarah create another question/post, the question she asked is related to my answer. She is basically asking me to answer the original question with more details, and adding an example. I think it would be more helpful for everyone that I update the original answer and add more details.

Comment: @Sarah If this answer was helpful, please accept it as answer to let other people know what worked.

Comment: Hi Timmy Chan, thank you, thank you soo very much, Yes my edit 1 is taking straight from the https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#indexable-types here, if you notice, Bob, Fred examples are there. But your explanation made so much more sense.

Comment: I do have a few more questions with syntax like this and I will tag you here for my new post on those questions if thats ok. I wish I could give 5 stars to your answer. Thank you much. Made so much sense.

Comment: @Sarah, you are welcome. Just tag me and I will possibly check the new post out.

Comment: Sure, is there a way to tag someone on a new post or will I need to come back here to tag you for that post?

Comment: You have to send a link here and tag me.

Comment: @Timmy Chan Here is a new post, based on your help here, thank you so much for helping. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64470126/understanding-typescript-interfaces