# Understanding typescript interfaces

Tags: javascript, json, typescript

I am tying to understand format of typescript/javascript and need help in understanding certain steps here. I am parsing a JSON file into an object and then trying to read values to update some values.

Thanks to Timmy chan I got some pointers from my previous post here, now building on that. [Objects creation using interface for JSON types in typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64235796/objects-creation-using-interface-for-json-types-in-typescript/64236136?noredirect=1#comment113940876_64236136)

Say I have this interface defined,

```
interface AllData {
  [value:string]:Row 
}

interface Row {
  eDate: string;
  mystate: string;
  mystateCity: string;
  numberofpeople: number;
}

let Data: AllData ;
```

I read the file like this and assign it to Data variable.

```
 const response = await fetchFile(fileName);
    Data= await response.json();
```

Now I want to create a new object which will only have rows

```
 const CountData: Row[] = {} // this gives error Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'CountyGraphRow[]': length, pop, push,
 
if I change it to 
const CountData: Row[] = []  // when to have {} or [].. What is the difference?

  for (const rowData in Data["value"]) 
  {
    console.log(rowData); //  this is coming out 0
    CountData.push({  //  error at TypeError: Cannot read property 'eDate' of undefined
      eDate: Data[rowData].eDate,  // Something is wrong in the way I am accessing them.
      mystate: Data[rowData].mystate,
      mystateCity: Data[rowData].mystateCity,
      numberofpeople: Data[rowData].numberofpeople > 20? 20 : Data[rowData].numberofpeople < 5? 5: Data[rowData].numberofpeople,
    })
  }
```

Here is how the file looks like

```
{
  "value": [
    {
      "eDate": "2020-03-01T00:00:00.000Z",
      "mystate": "state1",
      "mystateCity": "state1, ID",
      "numberofpeople": 2.973529602
    },
    {
      "eDate": "2020-03-02T00:00:00.000Z",
      "mystate": "state1",
      "mystateCity": "state1, ID",
      "numberofpeople": 2.973529602
    },
    {
      "eDate": "2020-03-03T00:00:00.000Z",
      "mystate": "state1",
      "mystateCity": "state1, ID",
      "numberofpeople": 2.973529602
    }
]}
```

--------------Update 2-------------

```
interface AllData {
    [value: string]: Row
}

interface Row {
    eDate: string;
    mystate: string;
    mystateCity: string;
    numberofpeople: number;
}

let Data: AllData;

Data = JSON.parse(`{ 
  "value": [
    {
      "eDate": "2020-03-01T00:00:00.000Z",
      "mystate": "state1",
      "mystateCity": "state1, ID",
      "numberofpeople": 2.973529602
    },
    {
      "eDate": "2020-03-02T00:00:00.000Z",
      "mystate": "state1",
      "mystateCity": "state1, ID",
      "numberofpeople": 2.973529602
    },
    {
      "eDate": "2020-03-03T00:00:00.000Z",
      "mystate": "state1",
      "mystateCity": "state1, ID",
      "numberofpeople": 2.973529602
    }
]}`);

const CountData: Row[] = [];

for (const rowData in Data["value"]) { // Data["value"] I am assuming this //will pick all objects   "value": [
   // {
     // "eDate": "2020-03-01T00:00:00.000Z",
// please correct me if I am wrong

   

 console.log(rowData); //  this is coming out 0
    CountData.push({  //  error at TypeError: Cannot read property 'eDate' of undefined
        eDate: Data[rowData].eDate,  // Something is wrong in the way I am accessing them.
        mystate: Data[rowData].mystate,
        mystateCity: Data[rowData].mystateCity,
        numberofpeople: Data[rowData].numberofpeople > 20 ? 20 : Data[rowData].numberofpeople < 5 ? 5 : Data[rowData].numberofpeople,
    })
}
```

Comment: What is `CountGraph`?  What is `countData` (lowercase `c` means it is not `CountData`)?  Why are you getting the property of `Data` whose key is `"value"`?  Do you even know if there is a `"value"` property in there?  (Oh, I guess you do know that, but `Data` is not properly typed.)  Please consider getting providing a [mcve] version of the code that demonstrates your issue when dropped into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/).

Comment: For your first question, `{}` is an empty *object*, whereas `[]` is an empty *list*. By default, JavaScript lists have `length`, `push`, and `pop` properties, so using `[]` in this case matches up with the specified type (`Row[]`, a list of `Row`s). `{}` has no properties, so you're getting an error saying that variable should have the required properties to line up with the `Row[]` interface. As for the rest, it is a bit hard to tell what is going on. You should edit the question and provide a bit more information, as jcalz suggested :)

Comment: For example, [this](https://tsplay.dev/PmLXbm) is the first step in getting an example others can use: get rid of the "file reading" part of the question, since it is not directly relevant and can be replaced with, for example, a JSON parse.  There are errors in the code unrelated to your question... fix those, and then if you have a question left (you will, because `Data` is mistyped), ask it.  Good luck!

Comment: Thanks @jcalz, sorry I had to rename some properties for security purposes. Replaced CountGraph with correct variable name. "value" is a field in JSON and its posted there.

Comment: @Nullromo, Made the edits.

Comment: @Sarah I beg you to [look at this code in an actual editor](https://tsplay.dev/4w1k2m) and fix problems unrelated to your question:  You're treating a `string`-valued field as a `number`, or perhaps you made the interface field a `string` when it should actually be a `number`.  You are accessing a non-existent `county` property.  The underlying problem here seems to be that you've annotated `Data` as having the type `AllData` when it should really be the type `{value: Row[]}` instead.  But there's too much in the way right now.

Comment: @jcalz thanks... sorry keeping security in mind, I skipped those items, just updated the code and fixed those errors. County property shouldnt have been there.  Please keep in mind that I am learning how the formats work and how parsing of JSON works, that is the purpose of the post.  I am still confused with your answer about what is wrong with how Data is defined. I am updating the code under update 2.

Comment: I understand that you have proprietary or encumbered code you can't show us.  That's fine, because a [mcve] is not intended to be a copy of your actual code.  Rather, it's best to have a toy example that you write from scratch that has *the same problem* as your code, without anything extra in there to distract people. With broken example code, people who want to help you spend extra time trying to fix the example before they can even get to your problem... if they ever do.  The TypeScript Playground is a great place to refine your examples before posting a question.  Good luck to you again!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oh, the issue with `{}` vs `[]`: the former is an empty object and the latter is an empty array.  In JavaScript, arrays are all objects but not all objects are arrays.  Specifically, arrays have all the array methods like `push()` that you care about.  If `CountData` is supposed to be an array, you can't assign `{}` to it, because it lacks the things arrays need.

Moving on the main part of your question:

---

The first problem here is that your interface

```
interface AllData {
  [value:string]:Row 
}
```

has a [string index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#indexable-types), which means "an `AllData` can have any number of keys of any `string` value whatsoever, and the property at each of those keys will be a single `Row` object".

*Please note* that the `value` in the above definition is just a placeholder and has no effect whatsoever on the type.  It is the same exact definition as

```
interface AllData {
  [x:string]:Row 
}
```

Anyway, your problem is that the `Data` you are reading does not have that shape.  It has a *single* key of exactly the name `"value"`, and the property at that key is an *array* of `Row` objects.  Meaning the following:

```
let Data: { value: Row[] };
```

---

Once you fix that, let's look at the smallest possible change to your code to get it working, and then improve from there:

```
const CountData: Row[] = [];
for (const rowData in Data["value"]) {
    CountData.push({
        eDate: Data["value"][rowData].eDate,
        mystate: Data["value"][rowData].mystate,
        mystateCity: Data["value"][rowData].mystateCity,
        numberofpeople: Data["value"][rowData].numberofpeople > 20 ? 20 :
          Data["value"][rowData].numberofpeople < 5 ? 5 : 
          Data["value"][rowData].numberofpeople,
    })
}
```

The loop `for (const rowData in Data["value"])` iterates over the *keys* of the `Data["value"]` array.  These are going to be the string values corresponding to the array indices: `"0"`, `"1"`, `"2"`, etc.  It is generally [not recommended](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in#Array_iteration_and_for...in) to iterate over arrays via `for..in`, because you'll get the indices as strings, possibly out of order, and with possible other unexpected things in there.  Still, it sort of works.

The main issue here, though: since you are iterating over `Data["value"]`'s keys, you need to read its properties by indexing into `Data["value"]`, not `Data`.

---

Let's stop iterating over array indices with `for..of` and use a regular for loop:

```
const CountData: Row[] = [];
for (let i = 0; i < Data["value"].length; i++) {
    CountData.push({
        eDate: Data["value"][i].eDate,
        mystate: Data["value"][i].mystate,
        mystateCity: Data["value"][i].mystateCity,
        numberofpeople: Data["value"][i].numberofpeople > 20 ? 20 : 
          Data["value"][i].numberofpeople < 5 ? 5 : Data["value"][i].numberofpeople,
    })
}
```

That is now guaranteed to happen in order and without any weird non-numeric indices.

---

Next improvements: let's stop saying `Data["value"]` since there's no reason to use bracket property access with a string literal that's a valid JavaScript identifier.  You can just use `Data.value`.

Also, instead of writing `Data.value[i]` a bunch of times, just save it to its own variable (hey we can call that `rowData` now):

```
const CountData: Row[] = [];
for (let i = 0; i < Data.value.length; i++) {
    const rowData = Data.value[i]; 
    CountData.push({
        eDate: rowData.eDate,
        mystate: rowData.mystate,
        mystateCity: rowData.mystateCity,
        numberofpeople: rowData.numberofpeople > 20 ? 20 : 
          rowData.numberofpeople < 5 ? 5 : rowData.numberofpeople,
    })
}
```

---

Next, you might consider using a [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) loop to directly iterate over the `rowData` *element*s without having to care about their numeric *indices*:

```
const CountData: Row[] = [];
for (const rowData of Data.value) { 
    CountData.push({
        eDate: rowData.eDate,
        mystate: rowData.mystate,
        mystateCity: rowData.mystateCity,
        numberofpeople: rowData.numberofpeople > 20 ? 20 : 
          rowData.numberofpeople < 5 ? 5 : 
          rowData.numberofpeople,
    });
}
```

}

---

Next, copying individual properties is fine, but if you're going to copy all or most of the properties, you can use [object literal spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#Spread_in_object_literals) to do it quickly (or [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) which is similar) and then just rewrite the one property you want to change:

```
const CountData: Row[] = [];
for (const rowData of Data.value) {
    CountData.push({ 
        ...rowData,
        numberofpeople: rowData.numberofpeople > 20 ? 20 : 
          rowData.numberofpeople < 5 ? 5 : rowData.numberofpeople
    })
}
```

}

---

Finally, if all you're doing is walking over one array and producing another array of the exact same size with each element in the input producing a single element in the output, you can dispense with looping and `push`ing entirely and use [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) instead:

```
const CountData = Data.value.map(rowData => ({
    ...rowData,
    numberofpeople: rowData.numberofpeople > 20 ? 20 : 
      rowData.numberofpeople < 5 ? 5 : rowData.numberofpeople
}));
```

}

---

Whew!  I think that's as good as I can make it.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.0.2#code/FASwdgLgpgTgZgQwMZQAQCUD2B3VBvYVI1KAEQWgC5UBnCGcAcwG5DiBbATzoqmroZgWbIlx7QAwiAid+9Jq2KowAV3YAjWJjgAHKJh0AbPsrWaYzVMAC+wYMYipyEBNTyoAbgkMqTWbADaALqo1pYA9OGoADwAtLGoEAAWaDJ6qCA0+F4+fjjB1gA0ypiOeAE5vnKCjEHU-rbAzgioALyoAFIAygDyAHIAdDoIMDRQABQABu5sAESVULPUASL4q0SzZLxLqLMATAAMh7EHAMwnAIwAKgcHlLf3BwO3BwBas4Xru2Iu0Duz4igFw+X1mP14Uhk-0BF2KAElSCClBtVBotLp9EZFtQ9gMAJwAdlOAFY9niAGxHVZFVYEZG7LZ-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-7TrO2h9guIwZZwGRZG+jhAeOkAgBW3iFUe6gMBAEDGJY6W8NlE6orAIBIPOB59bmqDGGeiRJM+I1QEIyTznQUAIAeP5-gBDgZG0qAHO1Nn0bxG4DMYM1JO1ADUJ1wdhyKxShS5oRhWFfPSeFOSZxEgBRVGPcitFGVBDEBO9LEirw3lKMJMi-c5REA0JwN+jIoPEB5qnScZ-2A8jUkafp9naZDr0wxZZgRijNl2Xpdn4+jSnExJnlQN51i+Ym-mZtmub5qFSQwFAJZ2EoQExbWcUuAlwQbSlSgdtuqAHhWADkjgTeOiQRdgzVoLtLmWDLSCTerg6QQMCzLf+4xrSAG1bet0RGwsB3TYwySned8EIYLIEKS07SoQsMMRGlwELUeBVARA4AqN4hilTz4AHlAAAeI7gBAEW+7xxQAFboY4jAgCr6e5DDfbKOzX3XahOjoZhl04c9ZkuJRzgM19YNwyYDcIEDgKI6I7ecagnfd6Ksq96YaJ0yj1BD5j1madpel44PXtExPKlY7b5MOdPK+z15X1M35rOBRzIWoAAYrW-6XR71bCzdosYE2EtBIoxC-mbt+d6OXaF74F2oA7HWUaWRdb9j7OoWsjg45DRoMUdCaAWgfwGAMAqhhMAGFVhkaAGVoCFT7DAEq5d76V2rg9HCSh64r0+hQjg7cd5uUbqxVudCZT+gYahcGnAx57w7rvWm685440XgZDht1eFk3spTZejCu68MZumPyjQT7BQLOffOfMBbRUcBXeKT9EovzfkQD+AEv5ex-nbXiF1iHIVIfddw0tex6wXOWHQpUo7jTQDoUCegYDh2GgVSamB1CZygEgRw2BpBJFoN44OtBOCQAQAnEaIBpzjUyCwogKCBidx4QIqyxgxGNwkfPAyIjHIz3yfTSRFMKn8LXgUqAB9mbEFsMo9mqi0BdBAMky6HYQBdm3PLHmqBGCYBHKnbBQ48GTWKggdxL5UBVwwvOSZz5SgpH-HM0qJiFpIGidNeg3DUCCxAPHLZhD5ksQQDoOa0BFoWKQStdBBgorATvrYpcG0-5QGuTocY39WiaXIQhbJuSvq8KKXIqppNSm41ETI1CEjN5SLqbI1eGpGnUlTIo2wQA)

Comment: Another thing: it looks like you're trying to "clamp" the `numberofpeople` value to be at least 5 and at most 20. In my opinion, it's a little nicer to use `max` and `min`, or to use your own function. For example, `numberofpeople: Math.max(Math.min(rowData.numberofpeople, 20), 5)` or define `const clamp = (value, min, max) => {return Math.max(Math.min(value, max), min);};` and then use `numberofpeople: clamp(rowData.numberofpeople, 5, 20)`. What I'm saying is I would prefer to use `max(x, y)` over `x > y ? y : x` for readability. Using `max` lets you avoid writing `x` and a literal `y` twice.

Comment: Thank you sooo very much guys, you are the best... I am going over the answer right now and will sure come back with questions.

Comment: First question right off the bat AllData {
  [value:string]:Row 
} "an AllData can have any.......... of those keys will be a single Row object". Did you mean that signature would be for shape like this.....  "value1" :{
      "eDate": "2020-03-01T00:00:00.000Z",
      "mystate": "state1",
      "mystateCity": "state1, ID",
      "numberofpeople": 2.973529602
    }"value2": {
      "eDate": "2020-03-02T00:00:00.000Z",
      "mystate": "state1",
      "mystateCity": "state1, ID",
      "numberofpeople": 2.973529602
    }  Just confirming my understanding is correct.

Comment: Yes, that data looks like it would match your `AllData` interface.

Comment: @jcalz sorry this is coming in late but I accepted the answer and I wish I could give it 5 stars. Thank you so much for such a detailed explaination.